# What other cities (outside Poland) are easily accessed by train from Kraków?

Tags: trains, international-travel, poland, train-stations, interrail

If I wanted to explore some other countries by train from Kraków, what countries are easily accessed? I seem to recall it can be quite difficult/take a long time to get from Poland to Ukraine by train.

Comment: There are relatively frequent and fast connections to all close neighbouring countries (Czech Republic, Slovakia and Ukraine). I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by a long time and precisely which country you are interested in. Fortunately the Man in Seat 16 has already done the research for you.

https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Krakow.htm

So you have a choice of two day-time trains a day from Krakóv to Lviv and Kyiv in Ukraine if that is your specific destination. There is also a sleeper from Warsaw.